# What does zero voltage or negative current mean in H-bridges?

Tags: h-bridge

[image]

I have looked around in the internet, but could not understand what does `zero voltage negative current` or `positive voltage negative current` mean. All that confused my mind.

Can anybody explain shortly about all these operating modes?

Thanks in advance.

My thinking for respective modes:

i) positive voltage is when the voltage difference between the motor is in such way that voltage on the left(according to the picture) is higher than the voltage on the right of the motor. So Q1 and Q4 open.

ii) have no idea

iii) I don't know how voltage on the right can be higher than voltage on the left. (assuming my thinking was correct for part i)

iv) if voltage is positive, how current flows in negative way?

v) have no idea

Comment: it appears that some information from previous questions may be required ... otherwise it is unclear what voltage and current is being referred to

Comment: The motor is marked with + on one terminal. Normally that would be positive, and (positive) current will flow into the motor. But the bridge allows other modes of operation  : if the other terminal is +ve, consider that -ve voltage. And for the "zero voltage" options, remember the motor is also a generator.

Comment: @jsotola in which manners? I don't think there is something needed from that datasheet in order to answer these.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have add an update, please see it. I am having a serious problem about "negative current"

Comment: @muyustan, i said nothing about a datasheet ... first sentence in your post makes a reference to the previous question

Comment: @muyustan oh, nevermind, there was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic H-Bridge.

[image]

There are five LEGAL states in a H-bridge there are then two ILLEGAL & four that do nothing.

The LEGAL states are:

1. All switches OFF - any current would freewheel by the supply & decay
2. 1 & 2 ON - positive current can build up in the load
3. 3 & 4 ON - negative current can build up in the load
4. 1 & 3 ON - zero volt loop that minimises load current decay OR shorts winding.
5. 2 & 4 ON - zero volt loop that minimises load current decay OR shorts windings.

[image]

Your question has identified five conditions

1. positive voltage, positive current

This would align to the state2 - charging as positive voltage is applied to the coil and there is positive current flow

2. zero voltage, positive current

This would align with State4 +ve or with State5 +ve as positive current carries on flowing via a diode and a switch. As there is no forcing voltage, this is referred to as a "zero voltage" state. The current will decay quite slowly

3. Negative voltage ,positive current

This would align with State1 +ve freewheeling. The inductive load keeps the current flowing in a positive manner but the voltage applied is negative. This will force the current to decay quite quickly

4. positive voltage negative current

This would align with State1 -ve freewheeling. The inductive load keeps the current flowing in a negative manner but the voltage applied is positive. This will force the current to decay quite quickly

5. zero voltage, negative current

This would align with State4 -ve or with State5 -ve as negative current carries on flowing via a diode and a switch. As there is no forcing voltage, this is referred to as a "zero voltage" state. The current will decay quite slowly

Comment: thanks for this nice and detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

To supplement JonRB's excellent answer,

The motor has two characteristics that (compared to a resistive load) can cause different relationships between current and applied voltage.

1. Inductance, which creates a back-emf voltage \$V = -L\frac{di}{dt} \$ proportional to the rate of current change. When the motor is switched off it generates a negative voltage which tries to keep the current going. This is the 'freewheeling' current that flows through the diodes when the transistors are turned off.
2. Inertia, which causes the motor to keep spinning in the same direction after the drive voltage is removed or reversed. Since the motor also acts as a generator, it can drive current into a short circuit when braking (both upper or both lower transistors turned on) or out of the power supply when the bridge output polarity is reversed.

Comment: why the minus sign at Voltage equation of inductor ? when the motor stops di/dt will be negative already

Comment: The minus sign indicates that the voltage is such as to oppose the current change. If it was the other way around it would cause the current to decrease ever more rapidly and 'snap' off, which violates [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law.). This has nothing to with motor movement, but simply the inductance of the windings (so it occurs even if the motor is stopped).